# Access SQL Query: trouble with * wildcard in WHERE AND LIKE statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

The query I'd like to execute:

```
SELECT *
FROM qryReportView
WHERE ((ID = 719) 
    AND (Name Like "*x"));
```

However when I run this query I get no records returned. Each criterion works on its own:

```
SELECT *
FROM qryReportView
WHERE ID = 719;
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM qryReportView
WHERE Name Like "*x";
```

Both queries return records as expected but when I combine them something goes wrong. I know there is at least one record for which both criteria are true.

NOTE: When I replace the * wildcard with an explicit name, I get the correct record returned. This is not a viable solution for me though because my query needs to select records ending in "x" with a number of possible prefixes.

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: What is that goes wrong?

Comment: What results do you get for each outcome when you run each query individually? I only ask this because I want to see if your row with ID of 719 has a name that ends with x; I am suspecting that it doesn't. Since you are using "AND", the query does not match both criterion, so the query brings nothing back. I believe you are wanting to use an OR in this case...

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with you query. Make sure that the record with ID = 719 indeed has the "Name" column value ending with "x".

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a logical operator issue.

When you ask an RDBMs for a samich and a coke, if it has a samich but not a coke, you get nothing. Which is what is happening here, you need an '`or`'

```
SELECT *
FROM qryReportView
WHERE (ID = 719
       OR 
       Name Like '*x');
```